# Custom Twig filter from bundle: Unable to load the runtime

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've a small twig custom filter in my project created following https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html . As long as it sits in `src/Twig`, it works as expected.

Now I'm trying to move it to a custom bundle (`vendor/turbolabit/tli-base-bundle/src/Twig/`) to make it reusable.

I moved the two files:

```php
<?php
namespace TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig;

use App\Twig\AppRuntime;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class TrimmerExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('trimmer', [TrimmerExtensionRuntime::class, 'trim']),
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\RuntimeExtensionInterface;


class TrimmerExtensionRuntime implements RuntimeExtensionInterface
{
    public function trim(string $value): string
    {
        return trim($value);
    }
}
```

I tagged it in `services.yaml`:

```yaml
TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig\TrimmerExtension:
    tags: [twig.runtime]
```

(I also tried as `tags: [twig.extension]`, even if it would be incorrect because this is a lazy-loaded filter, but it makes no difference)

I see it in `symfony console debug:twig --filter=trimmer`:

```
Filters
-------

 * trimmer
```

But when I try to use it (like I did before):

```html
 <div>{% apply trimmer %}      this must be trimmed              {% endapply %}</div>
```

it explodes:

**Unable to load the "TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig\TrimmerExtensionRuntime" runtime.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand exactly how this should be configured from the docs. The way I understand it the `TrimmerExtension` should be tagged `extension` and/or the `TrimmerExtensionRuntime` should get the `runtime` tag.

```
TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig\TrimmerExtension:
    tags: [twig.extension]

TurboLabIt\TLIBaseBundle\Twig\TrimmerExtensionRuntime:
    tags: [twig.runtime]
```